# Repeat replace one character (r) for next occurence

Tags: replace, repeated-commands

I'm using `r` a lot (e.g. for replacing `"` with `'` when refactoring code). Is there an easy way to do something like this:

For text: `values = ["a", "b", "c"]`.
Place cursor on first `"`, press `r'` to change to `values = ['a", "b", "c"]`.
Now we want to repeat that five times.
For example by pressing `5<Ctrl>r`.
To repeat previous `r` command five times for next occurences of `'`.

Would this be possible? And if so, how?

I know I can do `<Shift>v:s/"/'/<Enter>`. But this seems inefficient.

Please help making my life easier. ;)

Comment: Well, you could do `:s:':":g`

Comment: `<Shift>v:s` doesn't make any sense.  (It does the same as simply `:s`.)  I wonder if you thought that specifying a range will make the `:substiute` work on all matches instead of just the first one (per line) – that is not the case.  Instead, you need to `:set gd`° or append the `/g` global modifier to your `:s` commands.  ° Thanks @romainl!! :D  (Now I have to adapt all my `:s` mappings – thanks *A LOT*!… ;) )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, `<Shift>v:s/"/'/<Enter>` is certainly less efficient than `:s/"/'<CR>`.

Here are various ways to perform the same task:

```
f"           jump to next "
r'           replace it with a '
;.           repeat jump then repeat replace
;.           repeat jump then repeat replace
;.           repeat jump then repeat replace
;.           repeat jump then repeat replace
;.           repeat jump then repeat replace

/"<CR>       search for next "
cgn'<Esc>    change it to ' (Note: the gn command was introduced in Vim 7.3.610)
.....        repeat change 5 times

qq           start recording in register q
f"           jump to next "
r'           replace it with '
q            stop recording
5@q          replay recording 5 times
```

None of which being as efficient as `:s/"/'<CR>` which can be made even better with a small mapping:

```
nnoremap <key>      :s/
nnoremap <otherkey> :%s/
```

[image: demo]

Comment: How come you don't need to use the `g` flag?

Comment: Because of `:help 'gdefault'`.

Comment: Life changed forever

Comment: @romainl It seems that you mistyped `5@q` for `5aq`. Could you explain `cgn'<Esc>`? I cannot figure out what it means.

Comment: @FengYu, I fixed my answer, thanks. `cgn` means "change the next/current match of the last search", here the last search is `"` so the cursor is moved to the next `"` which is changed into a `'`. Since `c` puts us into insert mode we need to leave it with `<Esc>`. So that's `cgn` in normal mode, then `'<Esc>` in normal mode.